# How to identify data type from stdout in nodejs exec method?

Tags: python, node.js, stdout, child-process

I am executing  python script using Node.js child process -:

Here is code-:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('python prog.py', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log({'out': stdout})
}
```

prog.py-:

Case-1 -:

```
print(2)
```

Case-2-:

```
print('2')
```

In both the case i got, same output from nodejs program, that is`{'out': '2\n'}` i.e lost the information about their data type.

Is there any way to differentiate between string and integer from stdout?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, since stdout is a text output itself.

Maybe you can add some metadata to your output and then parse it, for example as JSON which is very easy to manage.

For example you could output something like:

```
print(json.dumps({ 'value': 2, 'type': 'number' }))
```

And then get it in Node.js:

```
const out = JSON.parse(stdout);
console.log({ out: out.value })
```

Or even easier if you don't need the name of the type, just dump the value encoded in Python as JSON (or other method), and once decoded in Node.js it will preserve the type (according to valid types in JSON: number, string, boolean, null, array, object).